# How to merge two observables with different types

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm trying to merge two observables from two different API requests but I can't figure out how.
The first API endpoint returns an observable of this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'A',
        element: {
            id: 'element_A_ID'
        },
        ...
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        element: {
            id: 'element_B_ID'
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

And the second API endpoint returns an observable of this:

```
{
    id: 'element_A_ID',
    name: 'Element A',
    description: 'Element A description',
    ...
}
```

So I want to call my first endpoint to get my array of objects, and then for each object to call my second endpoint to resolve the name of my object's element, something as follow:

```
this.getObjects().pipe(
    mergeMap(objects => objects.map(object => {
        return { 
            ...object, 
            element: { 
                id: object.element.id, 
                name: this.getElement(object.element.id).name 
            } 
        }
    }))
).subscribe();
```

In other words, this is what I have:

```
[
    {
        name: 'A',
        element: {
            id: 'element_A_ID'
        },
        ...
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        element: {
            id: 'element_B_ID'
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

And this is what I want:

```
[
    {
        name: 'A',
        element: {
            id: 'element_A_ID',
            name: 'Element A'
        },
        ...
    },
    {
        name: 'B',
        element: {
            id: 'element_B_ID',
            name: 'Element B'
        },
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

So I tried to use `forkJoin` to join both objects first and then `map`:

```
this.getObjects().pipe(
    mergeMap(objects => objects.map(object => forkJoin({ object, element: this.getElement(object.element.id) }))),
    map(objects => objects.map(object => {
        return { 
            ...object.object, 
            element:  {
                id: element.id,
                name: element.name
            }
        }
    }))
).subscribe();
```

But this is not really working as expected, maybe I only need to use `mergeMap` and a `map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two APIs, so you need to use `mergeMap` or `switchMap`.

```js
    const objectsWithoutName$ = this.getObjects();

    const objectsWithName$ = objectsWithoutName$.pipe(
      switchMap(objectsWithoutName => {
        // Get all elements using zip (or forkJoin if you know the observables will complete)
        return zip(...objects.map(object => this.getElement(object.id))).pipe(
          map(elements => {
            return objectsWithoutName.map(objectWithoutName => {
              // Find the element with the same id
              const element = elements.find(element => element.id === objectWithoutName.id);
              // Add the element property to objectWithoutName
              return {
                ...objectWithoutName,
                element
              }
            });
          })
        )
      })
    );
```

On your code:

```
mergeMap(objects => objects.map(object => forkJoin({ object, element: this.getElement(object.element.id) })))
```

`forkJoin` expects `Observable[]` as an argument. It will give you the result as an array when every `Observable` has completed. Your code does not meet the API of `forkJoin`.

```
    mergeMap(objects => objects.map(object => {
        return { 
            ...object, 
            element: { 
                id: object.element.id, 
                name: this.getElement(object.element.id).name 
            } 
        }
    }))
```

Shares a similar issue. `mergeMap` expects a `() => Observable` as its argument, not an array of objects.

Just refactor usages of `mergeMap`/`switchMap` and `forkJoin`/`zip` as the above snippet and your code will work.

Comment: Yes, the `mergeMap` example was to simplify the demonstration, but your solution with `zip` works thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will need a mergemap operator only. Here is the solution for the same.

```
this.getObjects()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(outer => {
      return this.getLowerObject((<any>outer).element.id).pipe(
        map(val => {
          return {
            ...outer,
            element: val
          };
        })
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val)); // this will print the combine value.
```

Here is the stackblitz link for the same
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-merge-observables?file=src/app/app.component.ts